# MySQL procedure doesn't recognise tables

Tags: mysql, procedures

It does not recognise the tables that I created above the procedure and it says: `unknown table "tourstats"` in field list.
The table tourstats contains no data intentionally because I insert data with the call of the procedure and when I execute the call of the procedure  it says: `unknown table "tourstats"` in field list and also the same for table `"participates"`.

My goal is to write a procedure that its input is a `tour_id`. If this `tour_id` is in the table `tourstats` in column `tourID`, I either delete it or update it and if it is not, I insert it. These 3 last actions are done using 3 triggers calling the procedure but that is the easy part.

Here is my code:

```
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TourDB;
        USE TourDB;

        CREATE TABLE if not exists PARTICIPATE (
            CID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
            TOURID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
            PAYMENT DECIMAL(9 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (CID , TOURID),
            CHECK (PAYMENT > 0),
            FOREIGN KEY (CID)
                REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (CID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY (TourID)
                REFERENCES TOURS (TourID)
                ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\.........\\participate.csv'
        INTO TABLE participate 
        COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES;

        CREATE TABLE TourStats (
            tourID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
            numCustomers INT NOT NULL,
            revenue DECIMAL(9 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (tourID),
            FOREIGN KEY (tourID)
                REFERENCES Tours (tourID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );



    #PROCEDURE
    delimiter //
    create procedure UpdateTourStats (IN tour_id varchar(10))

    begin

    if (tour_id) in (tourstats.tourID) and (tour_id) = (participate.TOURID) then
    #update
    begin
    update TourStats 
    set tourID = tour_id, numCustomers = count(participate.CID), revenue = sum(participate.PAYMENT);
    end;
    #insert
    elseif (tour_id) not in (tourstats.tourID) and (tour_id) = (participate.TOURID) then
    begin
    insert into TourStats
    values (tourid, count(participate.CID), sum(participate.PAYMENT));
    end;
    #delete
    else
    begin
    delete from tourstats
    where tourstats.tourID = tour_id;
    end;
    end if;

    end//
    delimiter ;

call UpdateTourStats ('tour2');
```

Comment: Is this in MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: it is MySQL server

Comment: `tourstats != TourStats`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: I replaced it but still get the same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that your first `IF` clause might be a problem.

`if (tour_id) in (tourstats.tourID) and (tour_id) = (participate.TOURID)`

You are asking if a value is in a column, or is equal to a column. I think that maybe this should be changed to

```
if tour_id in (select tourID from tourstats) 
and tour_id in (select TOURID from participate)
```

Now you are asking if a value is in a set of data.

Putting a column name directly in the `IN` clause seems to work for `SELECT` statements, but when I try using it in a stored procedure, I get the same error you are getting. If I change to the syntax I am suggesting, I don't get an error.

**Addendum**

Now that you are getting a different error, and I see that you are running the procedure with a value that you hope to get inserted into the table, let's test just that section:

```
if tour_id not in (select tourID from tourstats) 
and tour_id in (select TOURID from participate) then
begin
insert into TourStats
select TOURID, count(CID), sum(PAYMENT)
from participate where TOURID = tour_id
group by TOURID;
end;
end if;
```

I think your other statements might need similar tweaking. You should be able to work your way from the inside out, e.g. you should be able to run this successfully:

```
select TOURID, count(CID), sum(PAYMENT)
from participate where TOURID = 'tour2'
group by TOURID;
```

And if that works, try this:

```
insert into TourStats
#Plus the above SELECT statement#
```

And once you have that working, you are ready to drop that into your SP. Good luck.

Comment: yes i tried but i still get the same problem.. mysql is case insensitive..

Comment: still doesn't work for me.. I really do not know if it is my logic that is wrong or MySQL plays with me..

Comment: Did you change all of the conditionals in the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, but now the problem that i get is: Invalid use of group function

Comment: Sometimes it's a good sign to get a different error. Is there a group function in any of the triggers?

Comment: No but i didn't use the triggers yet. I just call it with: call UpdateTourStats ('tour2'); and then print the TourStats table to see if the entry is inserted

Comment: Check out the addendum to my answer, unless you've already got this solved.

Comment: Well that worked perfect!! No more problems, and the procedures and triggers work just fine! Thank you a lot!! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. Glad you stuck with it.